# Spectral theory without topology

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, eigenvector, topological-vector-spaces, vector-spaces

How much of spectral theory can be developed just working with vector spaces (finite or infinite dimensional) without referring to a choice of topology ?

Something along these lines, for example: let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, $V^*$ the (algebraic) dual, $A:V \to V$ a linear map, let the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ be the set of $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $A-\lambda$ is not invertible. Let $\sigma_p(A)$ (resp. $\sigma_c(A)$) be given by those $\lambda$ where $A-\lambda$ is not injective (resp. surjective), then $\sigma(A) = \sigma_p(A) \cup \sigma_c(A)$. We have $\sigma_c(A) = \sigma_p(A^*)$, where $A^*:V^* \to V^*$ the adjoint map.
We can think of $\sigma_p(A^*)$ as the set of $\lambda$ for which generalised eigenvectors exist, i.e., $\omega \in A^*$ such that $\omega(A v) = \lambda \omega (v)$ for all $v \in V$.

As an example, consider the space $V=\mathcal{O}(S^1)$ of holomorphic functions on the unit circle $S^1$ in $\mathbb{C}$. The operator $A$ of multiplication by $z$ has no eigenvectors, i.e., $\sigma_p(A) = \emptyset$.
 It is easy to compute all the generalised eigenvectors: for each $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|=1$ the functional $\delta_\lambda$ defined by $\delta_\lambda(v) = v(\lambda)$ for all $v \in V$ clearly solves $A^* \delta_\lambda = \lambda \delta_\lambda$, it is the only solution and there are no solutions for $|\lambda| \not=1$. So $\sigma_p(A^*) = S^1$ and it follows that $\sigma(A) =S^1$. All this does not depend in any way on a choice of topology.

As far as I understand the space $\mathcal{O}(S^1)$ is not even normable. On the other hand it seems reasonable that for a class of simple operators like $A$ a suitable idea of spectral theorem should be available, and I would expect that something so simple would have been already studied in detail.

Comment: The only reference I am aware of where infinite dimensional vector spaces are treated without referring to a choice of topological structure is Jacobson "Lectures in Abstract Algebra Vol.II Ch.IX".

Comment: In finite dimensions you do not need topology since all linear topologies on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent. In infinite dimensions  the topology matters

Comment: All of your definitions except the last one make perfect sense without assuming any topology, although the spectrum need not have any nice properties. The last one also makes sense, I think, but the algebraic dual can be pretty horrible so it's not clear what one gains by it

Comment: I'm more used to seeing the notation ${\mathcal O}(U)$ when $U$ is an open subset of the plane. What do you mean by ${\mathcal O}(S^1)$? Germs of functions that are holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $S^1$?

Comment: Regarding your example: I think the key point is that you are choosing a particular space and operator where things happen to work very nicely because of some kind of automatic continuity phenomenon. For instance your space *is* some kind of topological algebra and your multiplication operator happens to be continuous. Note that the **usual definition** of spectrum and point spectrum do not make any reference to topology anyway!

Comment: Regarding your first question: yes, or equivalently functions on $S^1$ that extend to holomorphic functions in a neighbourhood of $S^1$.

Comment: Regarding your second comment: that was the origin of my question: the spectrum does not depend on the choice of topology I put on my vector space. This is usually not clear in the usual approach in the literature.

Comment: Not only this example (and similar ones) is good enough, I also can completely control the algebraic dual (so I don't see how the usual comment that algebraic duals are horrible applies here), so I don't see how the introduction of a topology (i.e. restricting to the topological dual) should improve things. Moreover this type of space of (germs of) holomorphic functions is apparently not even in the usual classes of Hilbert or Banach spaces where usual spectral theorems work.

Comment: So it leaves my question open: is there some result on the spectral theory of at least some simple class of operators on spaces which are not obviously Hilbert or similar, which explains how things work in such simple example ?

Comment: @YemonChoi: Concering your comment that the usual definition of spectrum does not make any reference to topology: I'm not sure I agree here. I think it is common to define the spectrum of a bounded linear operator on a *normed* space to be the set of all $\lambda$ such that $\lambda - T$ is *invertible* - where invertible means bijective and with bounded inverse. The reason why topology does not occur in many definitions of the spectrum in the literature is that many sources consider only Banch spaces, where boundedness of the inverse of a bounded operator is automatic. [to be continued]

Comment: [continuation] I think for the question of the OP this means that it is most natural not to talk about the spectrum of linear operators on vector spaces, but of elements of unital algebras (say, over the complex field). Then one can obtain the usual definition of the spectrum of a bounded linear operator on a normed space by choosing the algebra to be the set of all bounded linear operators. If one wishes to consider a weaker form of invertibility instead (i.e. without the inverse being bounded), one can consider the algebra of all linear operators..

Comment: @gcm: Concering your question how much spectral theory can be developed without topology: the main obstacle that I see here is that every argument where the Neumann series comes into play does no longer work. This means we do no longer know that the spectrum is closed nor that it is bounded, and we do not have any kind of series expansion for the resolvent available. Moreover, we cannot use complex analysis (which plays a fundamentol role in usual spectral theory) since the Riemann integral of the resolvent cannot be defined without a topology available.

Comment: @JochenGlueck fair enough! I am used to talking about the spectrum of an element of a commutative unital algebra, without reference to any topology; and then as you say it is a theorem that when we are dealing with a bounded operator on a Banach space, this definition recovers the one you mention for bounded operators on normed spaces

Comment: gcm: I still think the question you posed at the start is a lot more broad than the examples you actually seem to be interested in, which as I said have hidden features. Have you tried looking up the study of operators on Frechet spaces or other LCTVS which are not Banach but certainly not "arbitrary" (e.g. they can't have countable Hamel bases)? I also am not sure why you claim you can completely control the algebraic dual of the space ${\mathcal O}(S^1)$ as Hamel basis arguments will produce all kinds of horrible functionals

Comment: Small correction of my first comment above: the italic "*invertible*" should of course be "not *invertible*".

Comment: @JochenGlueck thanks for pointing out some of the standard arguments of spectral theory that rely on the choice of a topology. while, according to the standard definition, the spectrum depends on the choice of topology (at least in the non Banach case, as you pointed out) it will always be a subset of the "general" spectrum that I defined above in the question. of course I don't expect to find a full spectral theorem, nevertheless the properties of such spectrum should still be interesting, but I could find nothing in the literature.

Comment: @YemonChoi In the concrete situation of the example I wonder why choosing a topology would improve the situation, since I can compute the spectrum, the point and generalised eigenvectors, and I suspect also state a form of spectral theorem. More generally I think about a given operator $A$ on a vector space $V$. If I can compute the eigenvalues and generalised eigenvalues of $A$, how and why should I choose a topology on $V$ ? By "control the algebraic dual" I meant that I can solve the $A^* v = \lambda v$ on the $V^*$, [cont]

Comment: [cont] i.e. find the point spectrum of $A^*$ which in turn gives the $\sigma_c(A)$ I mentioned in the question. I am not sure what are the "horrible functionals" that you mentioned...

Comment: Finally I haven't understood the reference to the spectrum of unital algebras, can you give me a reference on that ?

Comment: gcm, I apologize if we have been "talking past each other". It might be helpful if you could say a bit more about what area of maths you come from, where you learned spectral theory of linear operators or elements in Banach algebras, what you know about topological vector spaces, etc. As @JochenGlueck's comment has shown, different areas sometimes approach basic definitions from different angles and until we actually sort out what we both think the spectrum of an algebra element or operator _is defined to be_, I fear that discussions will not be terribly productive.

Comment: Furthermore, in your main question, I don't understand your remark about generalized eigenvectors, assuming you mean those non-zero $v$ for which there exists some scalar $\lambda$ such that some power of $T-\lambda I$ annihilates $v$. Why do you claim that the set of eigenvalues of $A^*$ acting on ${\mathcal O}(S^1)$ is equal to $S^1$?

Comment: @YemonChoi there is no need to apologise, I should rather thank you for your interest in this "vague" question. I've learned basic spectral theory from Reed and Simon, which is somehow standard for people coming from a mathematical physics side. My question is somehow philosophical. Why given an operator on a vector space I should make an (arbitrary, since there are non-equivalent ones) choice of topology to talk about spectrum etc when, at least in certain cases, I can compute all of it independently of any topological argument? [cont]

Comment: [cont] It seems to me that at least for the first steps this theory should be explained as a part of the theory of vector spaces and not TVS. For your question about generalised eigenvectors, I have updated the explanation of the example in the question. They are the "eigenvectors" which do not belong to the space $V$ itself, as is well known in the usual Hilbert space spectral theory, that I propose here to identify simply as solutions of the adjoint eigenvalue problem on $V^*$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu sorry I forgot to answer: I understand that there are inequivalent choices of topology on an infinite-dimensional vector space. That's exactly why I am asking what can be said of the spectrum of a linear map before such arbitrary choice. Maybe (and maybe probably) the answer is: not much. But then is there any reference in the literature where this quite basic problem is explained/analysed or at least dismissed ?

Comment: The holomorphic functions are usually defined on an open set. What do you mean by *holomorphic* function on the unit *circle*?

Comment: Germs of holomorphic functions on the unit circle (it is a standard definition), equivalently functions on $S^1$ which can be extended to holomorphic functions on a neighbourhood of $S^1$.